# Executor and Future class equivalents for JDK 1.4 to achieve execution timeouts

Tags: multithreading, java

Is there a framework that is compatible with JDK 1.4 that can simulate the same execution timeout functionality via thread management as in `Executor` and `Future` found in JDK 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the pre-Java5 [util.concurrent](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/intro.html) package. It's what the new concurrency classes were based on.

Answer (score 4):

There is a back port of the JDK 5.0 library which use the same classes names etc. http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/ It supports Java 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 5.0 and 6.  There was no Java 4.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I meant JDK 1.4. Edited now.