# asynchronous function with a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, java-5

I stumbled upon an question which is not clear for me.

> A. Using Java 1.4, wrap the following function in a thread so that it can be called asynchronously and provide a way for the return value to be retrieved at a later time:
>
> B. How would the same be done in Java 5

```
int someMethod(int i) { return i++; }
```

What I think is one of the solutions: Write a class with two public methods `void synchronized calculate(int i)` and `int getValue()` . The `calculate` starts the thread and and set a private variable.

In java 1.5 I can use AtomincInteger. Is that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In Java 1.5, I'm pretty sure you would use a [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to return the result. I'm not sure about the 1.4 equivalent, but it looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4473784/4794) covers the same ground.

Answer (score 0):

Mybe you can use double check locking in `1.5 or later`:

```
private volatile int privateValue = 0;

public void calculate(int i) {
    int result = getValue(i);
    if (privateValue != result) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (privateValue != result) {
                privateValue = result;
            }
        }
    }

}

public int getValue(){
    return privateValue;
}
```

Be sure you privateValue must declare as `volatile`.

More info about [double check locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625118/java-double-checked-locking).

[The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html).

Answer (score 0):

Let the `calculate()` method put the result in a `BlockingQueue queue`, and `getValue()` method invoke `queue.take()`, thus waiting in case the result is not calculated yet.

Note additional programming efforts required if the `getValue()` method can be invoked several times.